# How to extract raw VP9 stream from WebM file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, vp9

Is there a way to extract just the VP9 video stream from a WebM file?
Just the raw VP9 encoded data?
I mean the data you would usually use as the input to the VP9 decoder?

Which tool is the right one to do this? ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

VP9 does [not have](https://www.gpac-licensing.com/2016/07/12/vp9-av1-bitstream-format/) a pure raw bitstream format. The closest thing is the lightweight [IVF](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IVF) format - 32 byte global header + 12 byte header per frame .

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy stream.ivf
```